# gcc: using declaration at namespace scope shadows overload

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-errors, function-declaration

I have a strange problem with gcc 5.1.0. The following minimal code

```
// header 1
namespace A {
  template<typename X>
  inline constexpr X square(X x) { return x*x; }
}
// header 2
namespace A { namespace B {
    template<typename X>
    struct matrix { X A[3][3]; };
    template<typename X>
    matrix<X> square(matrix<X> const&) noexcept;
} }
// source, includes both headers
namespace A { namespace B {
    using A::square;         // no problem without this line
    template<typename X>
    matrix<X> square(matrix<X> const&M) noexcept
    {
      matrix<X> R;
      for(int i=0; i!=3; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j!=3; ++j)
          R.A[i][j] = M.A[i][0]*M.A[0][j] +
                      M.A[i][1]*M.A[1][j] +
                      M.A[i][2]*M.A[2][j] ;
      return R;
    }
    template matrix<double> square(matrix<double> const&) noexcept;
} }
```

causes the compiler error

```
test.cc:28:59: error: ‘A::B::matrix<double> A::B::square(const A::B::matrix<double>&)’ is not declared in ‘A::B’
     template matrix<double> square(matrix<double> const&) noexcept;
```

The error disappears if the line indicated in the source is removed. The code compiles fine with clang++, but gcc 4.8 also shows the error. I tried without success to find a related bug report on [gcc bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/), but that may not mean anything. So my main question(s): is this indeed a gcc bug and, if so, is it new?

---

This may well be related to the ancient [bug 37374](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37374), which showed similar behaviour without template. I have filed a new [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68313).

Comment: To me too it seems to be a bug in G++.